# How to access user-submitted values from a dynamic form?

Tags: php, mysql, form, array

I want to insert a row in my db-table with inputs from users. The form the users fill out is made with a foreach-loop:

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo '<div class="vm_kampe"><input type="hidden" name="kid['.$row->id.'" value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->hhold.' - '.$row->uhold.'</div>
          <div class="vm_result"><input type="text" class="vm_resultat" name="resu['.$row->id.'" placeholder="?-?" value="'.$row->resu.'"></div>
          <div class="vm_1x2"><input type="text" class="vm_1x2" name="bet['.$row->id.'" placeholder="1X2" value="'.$row->bet.'"></div>';
};
```

On the receiving-end, I tried this, but doesn't work:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$id = $jinput->get('kid');
$resu = $jinput->getString('resu');
$bet = $jinput->getString('bet');
$uid = $user->id;
$liga = 'bs';

foreach ($id as $key => $k) {
    $columns = array('id', 'uid', 'liga', 'resu', 'bet');
    $values = array($db->quote($k), $db->quote($uid), $db->quote($liga), $db->quote($resu[$key]), $db->quote($bet[$key]));
    $query->insert($db->quoteName('tip3_kuponer'))->columns($columns)->values(implode(',', $values));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->execute();
};
```

It just say something about:

> invalid argument in foreach....

Comment: `$jinput->get('kid');` will no doubt be returning a single string, not an array. You cannot loop through a string.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Where is your array of data from the form?

Comment: I guess I don't have one. How should I write that?

Comment: `$data = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->getArray();` Then loop through the `$data` array

Comment: Should this be instead of the  ˋ$jinputˋ or should both be there?

Comment: Have you defined `$jinput` somewhere already?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Forgot to write it, but I have editted my question now.

Comment: So use `$data = $jinput->post->getArray();`

Comment: And then use `$id = $data->get('kid');` ?

Comment: @lodder That doesn't work. I write out: "Error: Call to a member function get() on array".

Answer (score 1):

### First, you need to repair your damaged form html

```
// see the missing closing square bracket on each of your name attr ---↓-------------------↓-↓
                                                                       ↓                   ↓ ↓
echo '<div class="vm_kampe"><input type="hidden" name="kid['.$row->id.'←                   ↓ ↓
      <div class="vm_result"><input type="text" class="vm_resultat" name="resu['.$row->id.'← ↓
      <div class="vm_1x2"><input type="text" class="vm_1x2" name="bet['.$row->id.'←-----------
```

Because it is producing a one-dimensional `$_GET` (SUPERGLOBAL) array like:

```
$_GET = array(
    'kid[1' => '1',
    'resu[1' => 'somethingA',
    'bet[1' => 'somethingB',
    'kid[2' => '2',
    'resu[2' => 'somethingC',
    'bet[2' => 'somethingD',
    etc.
);
```

but really, you want:

```
$_GET = array(
    'kid' => array('1' => '1', '2' => '2', etc.),
    'resu' => array('1' => 'somethingA', '2' => 'somethingC', etc.),
    'bet' => array('1' => 'somethingB', '2' => 'somethingD', etc.)
);
```

So I'll recommend this loop code block (using more lines to improve readability of my answer):

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo '<div class="vm_kampe">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="kid[' , $row->id , ']" value="' , $row->id , '">';
        echo $row->hhold , ' - ' , $row->uhold;
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="vm_result">';
        echo '<input type="text" class="vm_resultat" name="resu[' , $row->id , ']" placeholder="?-?" value="' , $row->resu , '">';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="vm_1x2">';
        echo '<input type="text" class="vm_1x2" name="bet[' , $row->id , ']" placeholder="1X2" value="' , $row->bet , '">';
    echo '</div>';
}  // remove the trailing semi-colon here
```

### Second, change your submission method

Because you are delivering user-supplied data which will be saved to the database, `POST` is best/common practice versus `GET`.

### Third, collect and process the multi-dimensional `$_POST` data

(I didn't test this advice)

```
$kids = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->get('kid', [], 'array');
$resus = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->get('resu', [], 'array');
$bets = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->get('bet', [], 'array');

// just a general example of accessing the sets of data...
foreach ($kids as $id => $kid) {
    echo "For $id, kid is $kid, resu is {$resu[$id]}, bet is {$bet[$id]}<br>";
}
```

You should be able to integrate your query with the above.

When Joomla 4.0 rolls out, your INSERT query will be a perfect candidate for a single prepared statement with bound parameters, and iterated executions.

Comment: @Daniel I have answered both of your remaining two questions which do not have an accepted solution.  If they solve your issues I would appreciate the awarding of the green tick.  If either answer isn't quite right, or you would like some more explanation, please ask me.  Please always endeavor to progress all questions to a system-recognised resolution.